# Is there a way to add a smooth/ease transition effect to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, transition

I have this code to modify the position of an element on my page when user scrolls page a certain position of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 150) {
    jQuery("#tab_toggle #tab_toggle_bg").attr("style","top: 45% !important"); 
  } else {
    jQuery("#tab_toggle #tab_toggle_bg").removeAttr("style"); 
  }
});
</script>
```

Is there a way to add an effect similar to the CSS `transition: all 0.5s ease` to this when the scrollTop effect triggers?

Comment: You really should be using the 'css' property of JQuery instead of adding style attribute

Comment: you cannot use CSS property to add !important

Comment: You could use the .animate function of jquery but i am not sure if it will let you add the !important attribute !

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/easing/

Comment: David Z Maybe something like this   https://jsfiddle.net/j7y9rrrk/3/

Comment: You will have to play around with the params

Comment: You could do this easily without need for jQuery easing. Just add `transition: all 0.5s ease` to the `#tab_toggle #tab_toggle_bg` via CSS and it would give the easing effect. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jtgnw7nt/) is a sample which was forked from Varun's fiddle.

Comment: @Harry Absolutely right! you should have put this as an answer :) I wonder why I didn't think to try that

Comment: @DavidZ: I was a little unsure if you were allowed to edit the CSS. Added the answer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have access to the CSS file and are allowed to edit it, the simplest way to achieve the easing effect would be to add the required `transition` setting to the element via CSS. Any transition setting that is added to the element via CSS will remain applicable for property changes done through JavaScript also.

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
    jQuery("#tab_toggle #tab_toggle_bg").attr("style", "top: 45% !important");
  } else {
    jQuery("#tab_toggle #tab_toggle_bg").removeAttr("style");
  }
});
```

```css
#tab_toggle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
#tab_toggle_bg {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  top: 0%; /* an initial value for the property that needs to be transitioned is also required */
  transition: all 0.5s ease;  /* add the required timing function - ease, ease-in, ease-in-out, linear */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab_toggle">
  <div id="tab_toggle_bg">
    Scroll the page for more than 50px.
  </div>
</div>
```